# Printing a Value at the end of a list

Tags: java

Im stuck on a homework assignment and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I created an array of usernames and passwords but my instructions are

"Traverse the data using a traditional “For” loop, and print the information to the screen.
Search for Steve Rogers and print his information again at the end of the list."

I am able to have the code print the list to the screen but I dont know how to make it print one value at the end. Can someone guide me to how I would accomplish this? Code listed below:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication1;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class JavaApplication1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String names[] = {"Admin","Vale.Vicky","Lane.Lois","Kent.Clark","Wayne.Bruce","Parker.Peter","Rogers.Steve","Luther.Lex","Osborn.Harry","Prince.Diana","Linda.Zoel"};
        String password[] = {"Password1","ZZZZZZZZ","VVVVVVVV","AAAAAAAA","FFFFFFFF","RRRRRRRR","QQQQQQQQ","GGGGGGGG","YYYYYYYY","LLLLLLLL","PPPPPPPP"};
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
            System.out.println(names[i]+ "  "+password[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: What has Java got to do with JavaScript? The two languages have ***nothing*** to do with each other.

Comment: Thank you. Java is new to me, I thought javascript was a language used in Java. Sorry.

Comment: About as similar as ham and hamburger

Comment: @AngelGarcia Pay attention to the tag summaries - it says on the JavaScript excerpt "not to be confused with Java"

Comment: During traversal of names why dont you check the value with “roger.steves” and if it consist add it in an arraylist and at the end of the traversal get the value from list but you have to print value after for loop block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are looping through the arrays, look for `Rogers.Steve` and when you find it store the index.

```
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(names[i] + "  " + password[i]);
        if (names[i].equals ("Rogers.Steve")) index = i;
}
```

// now print it

```
if (index != -1)
    System.out.println(names[index] + "  " + password[index]);
else
    System.out.println ("Not found");
```

Comment: Thank you. I didnt think of just adding the value into a variable like that. This was my final code:

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
            System.out.println(names[i]+ "  "+password[i]);
        
        int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(names[i] + "  " + password[i]);
        if (names[i].equals ("Rogers.Steve")) index = i;
}
        // now print it

if (index != -1)
    System.out.println(names[index] + "  " + password[index]);
else
    System.out.println ("Not found");
    }
    
}